# Forms interpreting '' as 0 in def save. Refactor my solution

Tags: django

I've got all these radio groups and true false checkboxes in a modelform. The form posts '' if a checkbox was not checked or a button in a radio group was not selected. I am adding up all the values for the forms and want to interpret empty strings as 0. So I overrode the save function.

The save in my model code basically looks like this,

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.cei_total = 0
    self.aggbs_total = 0
    ceis = [self.cei_0,self.cei_1,self.cei_2,self.cei_3,self.cei_4,self.cei_5,self.cei_6,self.cei_7,self.cei_8,self.cei_9,self.cei_10,self.cei_11,self.cei_12,self.cei_13,self.cei_14,self.cei_15 ]
    for c in ceis:
        if c != '':
            self.cei_total += 1
    aggbss = [self.aggbs_0, self.aggbs_1, self.aggbs_2, self.aggbs_3, self.aggbs_4, self.aggbs_5, self.aggbs_6, self.aggbs_7]
    for a in aggbss:
        if a != '':
            self.aggbs_total += a # it's a radio group, a could be 1,2,3,4 if not ''
    # And so on...
    super(Survey, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

where cei_0-15 are BooleanFields or CharFields. And aggbs_0-7 are PositiveSmallIntegerFields.

There's got to be a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way of doing this:

```
self.cei_total = sum(1 for value in ceis if value)
self.aggbs_total = sum(value for value in aggbss if value)
```

Also, instead of defining these `ceis` and `aggbss` lists, you can use `getattr()`, like this:

```
ceis = (getattr(self, field) for field in self._meta.fields 
        if field.name.startswith('cei_'))
print sum(1 for value in ceis if value)
```

Comment: How would I pull the value from `getattr(self, item)` for the summation?

Comment: Still getting `invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''`

Comment: @broinjc see updated answer. In case of `aggbs` you should cast values to `int`: `print sum(int(value) for value in ceis if value)`.

Comment: @broinjc hm, why `int` is called with an empty string, it should be filtered out by `if value`..

Comment: I'm using ModelForm...from the looks of the DEBUG the value is `u''` ...`self 
<django.db.models.fields.PositiveSmallIntegerField: aggbs_4>
value 
u''`

Comment: is a python map function i could interpret '' as 0? shouldn't that allready be taken care of?

Comment: @broinjc I've updated the answer, better use `_meta.fields` instead of `dir`. Please check if it works for you.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49014/discussion-between-broinjc-and-alecxe)